# Trouble with using calloc with an array and returning a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

As a reference this is the second part of my assignment:

> `int* generateFibonacci(int size);`
>
> This function will take as input an integer called size. The value contained in the size variable 
>   will represent how many numbers in the Fibonacci sequence to put into the array. The function 
>   will use `calloc` to create the array of this size and then fill the array with `size` numbers from the 
>   Fibonacci sequence, starting with `1` and `1`. When the array is complete the function will return a 
>   pointer to it.

My trouble come in play when I get the error in line 8 "`warning: assignment makes and integer from pointer without a cast`".
Another error I get is in line 19 "`warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast`".

So my question is, how am I suppose to set up `calloc` to make the array with a size from a user, then return a pointer to it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* generateFibonacci(int size)
{
  int i, array[size];

  array[size]=(int*)calloc(size, sizeof(int));

  array[0]=0;
  array[1]=1;

  for(i = 2; i < size+1; i++)

  array[i] = array[i-2] + array[i-1];

  return *array;
}

void printHistogram (int array[], int size)
{
  int i, j;

  for(i=0; i <= size; ++i)
  { 
    for(j=0; j < array[i]; j++)
    {
      printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}   

int main(void)
{
  int array[100], size;

  printf("how big will your Fibionacci number be? ");
  scanf("%i", &size);

  generateFibonacci(size);
  printHistogram(array, size);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're using *both* a variable-length array *and* `calloc`. Instead, define `array` as `int *array;`. And you shouldn't bother casting the return of `calloc`. And you should probably be using `%d` in your `scanf` (unless you really want to accept the input as octal if it begins with a `0`).

Comment: `int *array = calloc(size+1, sizeof(int));`

Comment: array[size]=(int*)calloc(size, sizeof(int)); this line makes no sense. array should be a pointer not an array, also, remember to free the memory you allocated...., also, why do you create a static array in main and then you call generateFibonacci without saving the allocated buffer????

Comment: If this is C++, `array[size]` is non-standard, plus you should be using container classes and prefer `new` for memory allocation. Either way, don't cross-tag.

Comment: no this is just c, not c++.

Comment: `int *array = generateFibonacci(size);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY should that statement be in my main? before calling for my function?

Comment: @PeterDowling yes, If you do not do that, Return value from the function is discarded.

Comment: Here's another bug: `for(i = 2; i < size+1; i++)` should be `for(i = 2; i < size; i++)`

Comment: `return *array;` --> `return array;` [fix demo](http://ideone.com/wPVZ6X)

Comment: Okay so after the changes the program now compiles but i get an endless loop of "*"'s instead of the asterisks showing Fibonacci numbers

Comment: @PeterDowling Perhaps, you have to input the size of Fibonacci number of overflows or Become number really is greater.

Answer (score 1):

*how am I suppose to set up calloc to make the array with a size from a user, then return a pointer to it?*

For a 1D array of int * Use `printf()` and `scanf()`

```
int *array = {0}; //Note, leaving this initialization method for posterity 
                  //(See related comments below.)
                  //however agreeing with commentator that the more idiomatic
                  //way to initialize would be: int *array = NULL;
size_t size = 0;
printf("Enter order of array");
scanf("%d", &size);
array = malloc(size);//create memory with space for "size" elements
if(array){//do other stuff}
```

***But*** it is unclear from your example, and the comment if you really intend using a 2D array....

As stated in the comments, You have created an `int` array, then attempted to create memory for it.

```
int i, array[size];   
...   
array[size]=(int*)calloc(size, sizeof(int));//wrong
```

As it is created, `array` does not need memory.  Memory is created on the stack as automatic.
If you wanted a 2D array of `int`.  Then you could do it like this:

```
int  *array[size]; //create a pointer to int []
```

With this, you can create an array of arrays (in concept) in this way:

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++) array[i]= calloc(size, sizeof(int));//do not cast the output, not necessary
```

Now, you essentially have a `size x size` 2D array of `int`.   It can be assigned values in this manner:

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        array[i][j]=i*j;//or some more useful assignment
```

By the way, adjust the parameters of the `calloc()` statement as needed, ***but note***, casting its output is not necessary.

***Regarding the return statement***, your function is prototyped to return a `int *`.

```
int* generateFibonacci(int size){...} //requires a return of int *
```

If you decide to use a 1D array, i.e. `int *array={0}` (requiring that you allocate memory), then return:

```
return array;//array is already a `int *`, just return it.
```

If you are using the 2D array, then to return a `int *`, you must decide which of the `size` elements of the array you want to return:

```
return array[i];//where `i` can be any index value, from 0 to size-1
```

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, you are plain wrong. The C standard explicitly allows this form of initialization. Even more, `{0}` is the catch all initializer that is supposed to work for all basic types, arrays, `struct`, whatever.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant - I could not find your assertion in the standard, so ***[asked the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26896152/645128)*** on SO.  It appears it is not invalid to use this form of initialization.

Comment: @JensGustedt comment removed; it still does not do what it was supposed to do.