# Initialization of int pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, initialization

A very simple question regarding initializing an int pointer in C.  I was ***[just informed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26895418/645128)*** that:

```
int *varname = {0};
```

Is not valid.

I have not yet been able to find the explicit reference  that points this out, but have confidence (based on commenters rep) that it probably is not valid, Even though it compiles, builds and accepts memory from calloc/malloc statements okay.

Can someone please point out the specifics of why the above expression is not valid?

Comment: @molbdnilo - Okay, but is that statement similar to saying ***[duff's device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514118/how-does-duffs-device-work)*** is not valid, because it is not part of the C syntax?.  It is a hybrid, that through some coincidence happens to provide a way to do something, that is not explicitly pointed out in the standard.  Is this not similar?

Comment: You were misinformed. The C standard allows this form of initialization explicitly: **The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces.**

Comment: This maybe useful if you intend to use an array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589749/initialize-array-to-0-in-c

Comment: @ryyker, never mind, Grzegorz Szpetkowski had a decent answer first.

Comment: Are you trying to simultaneously define `varname `as a pointer and create an object for it to point to, similar to `char *ptr = "hello";`? If so, see my answer. If not, my answer is completely off the mark.

Comment: @KeithThompson - No, that was not my intent.  However I do disagree with you on one point:  Your answer is never that far _off the mark_.  I always walk away from them with a better understanding of some subtlety you are able to convey.  Thanks.

Comment: the right way to init a pointer is int *varname = NULL;

Comment: @user3629249 - which is equivalent to `0`, which in turn is equivalent to {0}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The:

```
int *varname = {0};
```

is just equivalent to:

```
int *varname = 0;
```

It's one of valid replacements of `NULL` object-like macro (either as `0` integer constant or such constant casted to `void *` type).

N1570 (C11 draft), 6.3.2.3/3:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>   cast to type `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant* If a null
>   pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>   pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a
>   pointer to any object or function.

Example (http://ideone.com/9917zk):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *varname = {0};

    printf("%p\n", (void *) varname);

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is just:

```
(nil)
```

(as a bonus part note that `nil` term was invented by [Alfred Tarski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Tarski))

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but what's going on here is that since the boundary of the array has not been defined, setting int *varname = {0} thus only initialises the very first element of the array, right?

Comment: @antikbd Not at all. What array? `varname` is *only* a pointer.

Comment: @antikbd: What array? The declaration creates a pointer object, not an array. The initialization `= {0}` is equivalent to `= 0`, which is equivalent to `= NULL`.

Comment: @antikbd: It's just a weirdness of C syntax, not really array initializer.

Comment: Oh I see. I have been heavily programming with pointers for the past couple of weeks and still get confused on stuff like these!

Comment: So there is NO difference whatsoever between int *varname = {0} and int *varname = NULL? If that's the case, then why is even the {} braces allowed?

Comment: @antikbd: `NULL` may be defined also as `(void *) 0` (I would it's say that one is common definition). It's slight difference, but it matters in some cases, but `0` (or `{0}`) is also valid representation of `NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

This is valid, we can see this by going to the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.7.8` *Initialization* paragraph `11` which says:

> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces. [...]

So:

```
int *varname = {0};
```

will initialize `varname` to a *null pointer*, since `0` is a *null pointer constant* as per section `6.3.2.3` *Pointers*:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression
>   cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant.55) If a null
>   pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting
>   pointer, called a null pointer [...]

and for completeness sake we know pointers are scalar types based on section `6.2.5` *Types*:

> Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar types [...]

Answer (score 3):

As Grzegorz Szpetkowski's answer says, that syntax:

```
int *varname = {0};
```

is valid. It just doesn't do what I suspect you think it should do. It's equivalent to

```
int *varname = 0;
```

which is equivalent to

```
int *varname = NULL
```

(assuming `NULL` is visible).

If my guess about what you're trying to do is wrong, the rest of this answer doesn't apply.

---

**Based on the comments, it looks like that's not what the OP was trying to do. Not sure whether to delete this answer or not; it could be a good answer to some other question.**

---

You can initialize a `char*` pointer to point to a string literal:

```
char *cptr = "hello";
```

The string literal `"hello"` implicitly creates an anonymous array object with static storage duration; the initialization causes `cptr` to point to that array's initial element.

Prior to C99, there was no equivalent syntax for defining a non-character pointer and simultaneously creating something for it to point to.

C99 added *compound literals*. For example, this:

```
(int){42}
```

creates an `int` object with the value `42`. Unlike a literal `42`, this actually creates an *object*, not just a value -- which means it has an address.  So this:

```
int *iptr = &((int){42});
```

creates an anonymous `int` object with an initial value of `42`, and initializes `iptr` to point to it. (If your compiler supports compound literals.)

Compound literals are usually used for array and structure types, but they're also valid for scalar types.

One thing to watch out for: the array created by a string literal always has static storage duration, meaning it exists during the entire execution of the program. The storage duration of the anonymous object created by a compound literal depends on where it appears. If it's inside a function, the object has *automatic* storage duration, which means it ceases to exist as soon as execution leaves the nearest enclosing block.

So given:

```
char *cptr = "hello";
```

you can safely return the value of `cptr` from a function, and it will continue to be valid. But given:

```
int *iptr = &((int){42});
```

returning the value of `iptr` from a function would be dangerous, since the object it points to will cease to exist before the caller gets the pointer value.

A simpler way to do this kind of thing is to define the object yourself:

```
int obj = 42;
int *iptr = &obj;
```

You can define `obj` as `static` if necessary.

Comment: @ryyker: "My intent is to initialize `int *array` to `0`." -- Just to be clear, you mean you want to make `array` a null pointer, right? (In the linked answer, the initialization isn't strictly necessary at all, since the object is unconditionally assigned a different value. BTW, `{0}` is a valid initializer for an object of any type.